# VSInstr not honoring EXCLUDES (VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, instrumentation

I'm at a loss here. Our unit tests are instrumented by VSInstr and then profiled by PerfMon (code coverage). We have an extensive list of excludes that we use:

```
/EXCLUDE:"boost::*"
/EXCLUDE:"ATL::*"
/EXCLUDE:"UnitTestNamespace::*"
/EXCLUDE:"cppunit::*"
```

...etc...

When our unit tests are run, the code coverage file gives us a listing of all of our code, plus all the namespaces and classes that were excluded. No errors were generated by VSInstr. We compile our unit tests with the /PROFILE linker flag.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

EDIT: I tried excluding only ATL::, but it still included it. So my theory that the command line was too long was proven wrong.

Comment: The stackoverflow editor parsed out the astrixes. They sit after the scope operator ::.

Comment: Displays better if you format it as code.

Answer (score 3):

No quote characters in ours, e.g.,

```
%vsinstr% <someDLL> @CPPCoverageExcludes.txt
```

where CPPCoverageExcludes.txt looks like this:

```
/exclude:std::*
/exclude:ATL::*
...
/exclude:_com_error::*
/exclude:_com_issue_error::*
/exclude:_com_issue_errorex::*
/exclude:_com_raise_error::*
```